# How variables get stored in memory in C, According to their types

Tags: c, memory

So I was trying to understand how C stores my variables in memory and I've been doing good enough till I faced this problem:

I wrote the following simple program that tells me where the variables are getting stored one by one so I can know the difference between the types, but I couldn't make any links the number looks so arbitrary in the same time I believe it has to do with the types. So, any clues why the characters get ALWAYS the lower memory addresses even if they are declared last?

```
int main ()
{
    int integer1 = 6;
    int integer2 = 2;
    int integer3 = 3;
    char character1 = 'C';
    char character2 = 'B';
    char character3 = 'D';
    char string1[4] = "Hi!";
    char string2[4] = ":D";
    char string3[4] = "ack!";

    printf ("integer1 : %d, at %p\n", integer1, &integer1);
    printf ("integer2 : %d, at %p\n", integer2, &integer2);
    printf ("integer3 : %d, at %p\n", integer3, &integer3);
    printf ("character1 : %c, at %p\n", character1, &character1);
    printf ("character2 : %c, at %p\n", character2, &character2);
    printf ("character3 : %c, at %p\n", character3, &character3);
    printf ("string1 : %s, at %p\n", string1, string1);
    printf ("string2 : %s, at %p\n", string2, string2);
    printf ("string3 : %s, at %p\n", string3, string3);
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
integer1 : 6, at 0x7ffe40915b40
integer2 : 2, at 0x7ffe40915b44
integer3 : 3, at 0x7ffe40915b48
character1 : C, at 0x7ffe40915b3d
character2 : B, at 0x7ffe40915b3e
character3 : D, at 0x7ffe40915b3f
string1 : Hi!, at 0x7ffe40915b4c
string2 : :D, at 0x7ffe40915b50
string3 : ack!, at 0x7ffe40915b54
```

EDIT : Compiler : GCC 7.3.0

Comment: The compiler puts them wherever it thinks is best. Typically, it tries to put the `int` variables at addresses that are a multiple of the `sizeof(int)`. In your case, an `int` is 4 bytes so the `int` addresses are multiples of 4.

Comment: This is implementation-dependent, there are no requirements on how memory is arranged. The compiler probably rearranges the variables to minimize the amount of memory they use. Larger data types generally have more coarse alignment requirements.

Comment: It *might* be related with the fact that `sizeof(char)` is the unit size... but really, it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: this is compiler specific, if you want to know for your compiler then you will need to include it as part of your question

Comment: BTW keep in mind that on x86 lower addresses means "later in the stack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are dealing with auto variables. There is no formal specification of how auto variables are implemented but in any system you are likely to find they are going to be on the stack.

(Assuming no optimization)

If you look at the generated code for your main () function (-S option, usually) you are likely to find a statement that looks something like

```
  MOV  SP, BP
  DECL #SOMENUMBER, SP
```

where SOMENUMBER is the number of bytes your main function needs for local variables.

Then the compiler assigns offsets from the SP register for each variable. It looks like then:

```
  1(SP) ; is character1
  2(SP) ; is character2
  3(SP) ; is character3
  4(SP) ; is integer1
  8(SP) ; is integer2
  12(SP) ; is integer3
  16(SP) ; is string1
  20(SP) ; is string2
  24(SP) ; is string3
```

Stacks normally grow downward so the lower variable addresses will have smaller offsets.

Then the compiler needs to initialize each location on the stack.

The compiler's allocator will figure out how to do this mapping. You'd need to look at the GCC code to figure out why it is taking the path it is.

Throwing in

```
 short short1 ;
 long long long1 ;
 char str[] = "12345" ;
```

Might give you some interesting results to see how different sizes affect the allocator.

Comment: Thanks loads! I guess that sums it up finally

Answer (score 4):

The ordering of variables in memory is an implementation detail of the compiler.  There are no guarantees as to what it will look like.

That being said, it appears that the compiler was attempting to lay out the variables in such a way that all are properly aligned without any padding between them, i.e. it did so to save space.

Comment: But, if that's the case! how overflow exploits work if no one knows how variables get stored. also if you look closely the variables of same type are well aligned one after the other perfectly

Comment: @GlenE.Renner If you know what compiler was used, you can predict the layout.

Comment: @GlenE.Renner so that's your hidden agenda: how to break a system.

Comment: @GlenE.Renner Variables with the same alignment requirement can be grouped together, since no padding is needed between them.

Comment: @GlenE.Renner you have to run the compiler and then figure out how it decided to lay out the variables. For some compilers it might be predictable and then you can predict it.

Comment: @GlenE.Renner Once the code is compiled, you can see what the layout is, but you can't really predict it ahead of time.  Even then, many compilers these days use address space layout randomization, which means the actual addresses change every time the program runs.  That's done specifically to make exploiting a buffer overflow more difficult.

Comment: @WeatherVane more like how to protect a system :)

Comment: @GlenE.Renner One of the main protections against buffer overflow attacks is disallowing stack execution.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the useful info, I noticed as well that variables get stored according to their size, no matter what I always get characters first, then integers, then long then strings.

Comment: @GlenE.Renner which is what this answer says.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not exactly but it helped